# Slicing a dataset containing 2 independent and 1 dependent variables. I want to access the data with the independent variables separately

Tags: python, slice

Good morning.
I have a 3D dataset, in which one variable is simultaneously measured as a function of 2 others variables. I have a code that bins the data and plot the dependent variable as a function of one independent variable. Now I want the plot as a function of the other independent variable

This is the code that does the bin (it is a function)

```
for i in range(len(nroft_Ebins)-1):
    timedelay,energy,alpha = binner2D(timedelay_sig,energy_sig,alpha_sig,nroft_Ebins[i][0],nroft_Ebins[i][1])
    lastbin = int(len(timedelay)-1)
    plot(energy, alpha[0], label= str(round(timedelay[1],2))+'ps')
    plot(energy,alpha[int(lastbin/2.)], label= str(round(timedelay[int(lastbin/2.)],2))+'ps')
    plot(energy,alpha[lastbin], label= str(round(timedelay[lastbin],2))+'ps')
```

As you can see from the code, timedelay and energy are the independent variables and alpha is the dependent one. The 3 plots generate graphs of alpha Vs energy at 3 fixed values of the timedelay (slicing the graph in the direction perpendicular to the timedelay). Now I want the opposite, graphs of alpha Vs timedelay at fixed energy values.